# Convert a range into a sequence without using a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Having a table like this:

```
FromKey | ToKey | Value
------------------------
 1      |  4    | AAA 
 5      |  6    | BBB
```

what is the most efficient way to get the following result?

```
Key  | Value
-----------------
 1   | AAA 
 2   | AAA 
 3   | AAA 
 4   | AAA 
 5   | BBB 
 6   | BBB
```

I know how to do it using a table function and CROSS APPLY, but that approach is slow for big tables. I wonder if there is a faster solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to try (full example, runnable as-is):

```
-- Dummy data
DECLARE @Data TABLE (FromKey INTEGER, ToKey INTEGER, Value VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Data VALUES (1,4,'AAA'),(5,6,'BBB')

-- table of numbers, 1-100 for demo purposes
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (Num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT @Numbers
SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id)
FROM sys.objects

SELECT n.Num, d.Value
FROM @Data d
    JOIN @Numbers n ON d.FromKey <= n.Num AND d.ToKey >= n.Num
```

What I would do, is create a physical "Numbers" table in your database, and populate with numbers from 1 to n, where n is a large enough number to cover your needs. This would be a one off table/data creation - but then the table can be used for purposes like the above.

Comment: Ahhh, numbers tables, is there anything you *can't* do? :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as the difference between FromKey and ToKey is less than 2047

```
declare @t table(FromKey int, ToKey int, Value varchar(3))
insert @t values(1,4, 'AAA'), (5,6, 'BBB')

select t.ToKey  - m.number [Key], t.Value 
from @t t
join
master..spt_values m ON type = 'P' AND number <= ToKey - FromKey
order by 1
```

Here is a recursive solution:

```
declare @t table(FromKey int, ToKey int, Value varchar(3))
insert @t values(1,4, 'AAA'), (5,6, 'BBB')

;with a as
(
select FromKey [Key], ToKey,  Value from @t
union all
select [Key] + 1, ToKey, Value from a
where [Key] < ToKey
)
select [Key], Value from a
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table
(
FromKey int,
ToKey int,
Value  varchar(10)
)

insert into @t values(1,4,'AAA')
insert into @t values(6,9,'BBB');
with tab as 
( 
 select FromKey , ToKey,  Value from @t 
 union all 
 select FromKey + 1, ToKey, Value 
 from tab where FromKey < ToKey 
) 
 select FromKey, Value from tab order by 1
```